# How to update Xcode?

Tags: high-sierra, xcode, macports

I have a Mac running High Sierra, version 10.13.6. When running MacPorts I get the following error message that I should update my Xcode installation:

> Error: The installed version of Xcode (8.3.1) is too old to use on the
>   installed OS version. Version 9.3 or later is recommended on Mac OS X
>   10.13.

Running `xcodebuild -version` confirms this:

> Xcode 8.3.1
>
> Build version 8E1000a

But when I launch App Store I can't find any updates.

Has anyone an idea how I can update Xcode including command line utilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably just install the current version from the MAS.

https://itunes.apple.com/app/xcode/id497799835?l=en&mt=12

The command line utilities are included within the Xcode bundle. On first launch symlinks to the utilities are installed into the system so they can be accessed from the Terminal/command line.

There is also a separate Command Line Tools package available from the Developer Account download archive (needs an Apple Developer Account).

https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=for%20Xcode

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37044755/2540625) answer on Stack Overflow helpful. If I launch App Store.app and it doesn't list Xcode under my available Updates, instead I search for Xcode, I click on the search result, and it shows a large, blue Update button in the upper-right corner to click.

In this screenshot, the Update button has been replaced by the circular progress indicator (I'm awaiting the download to finish).

[image: screenshot]

- App Store Version 3.0 (1004.6.21)
- macOS Catalina Version 10.15.4 (19E287)